# Нужно в массив добавить массив.Количество вводит пользователь

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию заполнения пользовательскими данными двумерного массива. Длину основного массива и внутренних массивов задаёт пользователь. Значения всех элементов всех массивов задаёт пользователь.

```js
function arrAdd() {
    let arr = [];
    let amount = +prompt("Введите количество елементов в первом массиве");

    for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        arr.push([]);
    }
    // Нужно перебрать первый массив и добавить в каждый елемент n массивов

    for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        let amount2 = +prompt("Введите количество елементов в " + (i + 1) + " массиве");
        for(let i = 0; i < amount2; i++) {
            arr[i].push([]);
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

let functionResult = arrAdd();
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: после того, как вы спросили сколько элементов во вложенном массива вам бы надо спросить эти сами элементы,  а не пустой массив добавлять

Comment: Первые массивы создал.Не могу разобраться как создать в нем ещё массивы

Comment: вы можете редактировать вопросы, не надо их клонировать. что вот это по вашему?   `arr.push([i][text]);` ?

Comment: Что в каждый массив я добавляю элемент

Answer (score 0):

```js
function arrAdd() {
    let arr = [];
    let amount = +prompt("Введите количество массивов в первом массиве");

    for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        arr.push([]);

        let amount2 = prompt("Введите количество елементов" + (i + 1));

        for(let j = 0; j < amount2; j++) {
            let elem = prompt("Введите текст" + (j + 1));
            arr[i].push([elem]);
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

let functionResult = arrAdd();
```

Comment: зачем вы добавляете `[elem]` а не просто `elem` ?